# How to use replace_na if column is integer

Tags: r

I am trying to replace "NA" in a dataframe that has 3 columns: Day, Month, and Temperature.

nas <- mydata %>% replace_na(list(Temp = "unknown"))

but I get this error:
Error in `vec_assign()`:
! Can't convert `replace$Temp`  to match type of `data$Temp` .

Example of two records in my data

```
 Day    Month   Temp
 30     7       68
 31     7       NA
```

Thanks!

Comment: Convert to character first with `mutate(Temp = as.character(Temp))`

Comment: Shorter `my_data[is.na(my_data)] <- 'unknown'`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with the newest versions of tidyr.

However, for tidyr version 1.1.4 for instance, replace_na() did not require mutating type first.

The solution is to mutate the type as stated in @IceCreamToucan's comment :

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

nas <- mydata %>% 
  mutate(Temp = as.character(Temp)) %>% 
  replace_na(list(Temp = "unknown"))
```